# Avoiding email while registering a user in Authy

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, authy

I am creating a sign up route where I will ask for phone number first and then, after verification, I will get the other information. I am using twilio Authy for that purpose. From the documents, i have noticed that email address is a required field while registering a user. Is there any way by which I can register a user without email address or can i use a default email address for every user?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can add an Authy user without taking personally identifiable information [following the process in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users#add-a-user-without-providing-email-or-phone-number). Note that the user will have to be using the Authy app.

To do so, you need to create a JWT containing the following information:

```
{
  "iss": "{authy_app_name}",
  "iat": {issue date in NumericDate},
  "exp": {expiration date in NumericDate},
  "context": {
    "custom_user_id": "{custom_user_id}",
    "authy_app_id": "{app_authy_id}"
  }
}
```

Then add the JWT to a URL that you turn into a QR code. The URL format should be:

```
authy://account?token={JWT}
```

You can then poll or set up to receive a webhook to get notified of the user's authy_id once they have scanned the QR code. You can [read more on this in the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users#generate-the-qr-code-from-the-transaction-string).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: what if user is not using any Authy app ?

Comment: Then follow the instructions under ["Allow user to set up other authenticator apps"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users#optional-allow-user-to-set-up-other-authenticator-apps-like-google-authenticator) in the documentation.

Comment: still for that user must have authy app and his authy id !

Comment: The user does not need the Authy app, but you do have to [create a user through the API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/users#enabling-new-user) first, to get their Authy ID, and then [generate a QR code for them](https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/api/one-time-passwords#other-authenticator-apps). This method does require personally identifiable information though. If you want to do 2FA with a QR code and without capturing an email/phone number, you won’t be able to use the Authy API. For new use-cases, we actually recommend the [Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api) now.